# Can't run CreateExecutable example

Tags: compile, ccompilerdriver

I'm trying to run [this](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/CCompilerDriver/ref/CreateExecutable.html) example from the Wolfram website, on Linux Mint 16.

```
Needs["CCompilerDriver`"];
hello = CreateExecutable["
    #include <stdio.h>
    int main(){
      printf(\"hello world\\n\");
    }
    ", "hello"]
Import["!" <> QuoteFile[hello], "Text"]
```

But at the CreateExecutable call I get the message

```
CreateExecutable::cmperr: Compile error: collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

And the code returns `$Failed` (plus some error messages from the Import call, that depends on CreateExecutable working).

Comment: Prints `Hello world` on Ubuntu 15.10 (Linux Mint 16 is based on Ubuntu 13.10). Did you install a c compiler? What does `CCompilers[]` return?

Comment: I use GCC outside of Mathematica and `CCompilers[Full]` lists GCC.

Comment: What if you remove the `printf` line and then the `#include` line?

Comment: When something goes wrong with compilation, the very first thing to do is to look at the compilation command line and the compiler output.  Add the options `"ShellCommandFunction" -> Print` and `"ShellOutputFunction" -> Print`.  The output will tell you what is wrong.

Comment: I added these options and it returns, in the end of the output: `/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lstdc++`

Comment: Seems more like a c++ concern than a MMA's.

Comment: Indeed, I updated GCC (https://help.ubuntu.com/community/InstallingCompilers) and it now works. SE related question now: how can I mark this question as solved?

Comment: @gapolo You can provide a short answer yourself and accept it. That is encouraged behavior here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I added the options `"ShellCommandFunction" -> Print` and `"ShellOutputFunction" -> Print` to CreateExecutable, they print the output of the compilation to Mathematica, thus it allows debugging.

On the output message there was the line `/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lstdc++`,
which indicates an issue with the compiler. I installed the C++ compiler (G++) following [these instructions](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/InstallingCompilers) and the code worked.

With the options added, the code looks like:

```
Needs["CCompilerDriver`"];
hello = CreateExecutable["
    #include <stdio.h>
    int main(){
      printf(\"hello world\\n\");
    }
    ", "hello",
    "ShellCommandFunction" -> Print,"ShellOutputFunction" -> Print]
Import["!" <> QuoteFile[hello], "Text"]
```

Comment: Did you *update* gcc or did you *install a C++ compiler* in addition to the C compiler than you already had?  From the error it appears that the latter is needed.  While the code is plain C (not C++), typical uses of Mathematica's compilation functions necessitate linking against libraries that in turn depend on the C++ standard library.  Thus `CreateExecutable` will by default try to link against `libstdc++` even when compiling only C code.